# 'SQLSTATE[HY093]' with my search query

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am having some trouble getting my search query to work. I get this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter

```
     $test = $_POST["test"];

    $query='SELECT * FROM news WHERE name LIKE :search OR category LIKE :search';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $test . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {

    echo $row ['id'];
    echo $row ['name'];

    }
```

it only works if i remove `OR category LIKE :search`

Comment: Can't use a placeholder twice. Change it to `:search1` and `:search2` and bind it to the same value.

Comment: thanks for your help with this, it worked just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because you are trying to re-use the same bind variable again. Try using a different one like

```
$query='SELECT * FROM news WHERE name LIKE :search OR category LIKE :search1';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $test . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':search1', '%' . $test . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Also might not be an integer.